# adding texture to a json object - three.js

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

I am trying to add texture to my 3D Dog JSON model which I have exported from clara.io. I have used Ojectloader to load the 3D model and then tried using a Textureloader to load the texture, but the texture doesn't seem to load onto the model.

Maybe my code is wrong, or is in the wrong place. I have tried looking at other examples of how people have done this but not gotten much luck. As I said the problem is the texture doesn't seem to load the image onto the model. Also there are no errors on the console in chrome as well.

If anyone could be any help, thank you.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <title>three.js webgl - loaders - Clara.io JSON loader</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
            <style>
                body {
                    font-family: Monospace;
                    background-color: #000;
                    color: #fff;
                    margin: 0px;
                    overflow: hidden;
                }
                #info {
                    color: #fff;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 10px;
                    width: 100%;
                    text-align: center;
                    z-index: 100;
                    display:block;
                }
                #info a, .button { color: #f00; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer }
            </style>
        </head>

        <body>

            <script src="three.js"></script>
            <script src="Detector.js"></script>
            <script src="stats.min.js"></script>
            <script src="UnpackDepthRGBAShader.js"></script>
            <script src="ShadowMapViewer.js"></script>
            <script src="dat.gui.min.js"></script>
            <script src="OrbitControls.js"></script>

            <script>
                var container, stats;
                var camera, scene, renderer;
                var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
                var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
                var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
                init();
                animate();
                function init() {
                    container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                    document.body.appendChild( container );
                    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
                    camera.position.z = 4;
                    // scene
                    scene = new THREE.Scene();
                    var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x444444 );
                    scene.add( ambient );
                    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffeedd );
                    directionalLight.position.set( 0, 0, 1 ).normalize();
                    scene.add( directionalLight );

                    //new attempt at a texture and object loader
                    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
                    loader.load("dogtexture.jpg", function ( texture ) {
                        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture });
                        var objectLoader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
                        objectLoader.load( "blue-dog1.json", function( obj, texture ) {
                            obj.scale.set( .04, .04, .04);
                            scene.add( obj,texture );
                        });
                    });


                    // BEGIN Clara.io JSON loader code
                    //var objectLoader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
                    //objectLoader.load("blue-dog.json", function ( obj ) {
                    //obj.scale.set( .045, .045, .045);
                     //scene.add( obj );
                    //});

                    //var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
                    //loader.load("dogtexture.jpg", function ( texture ) {
                    // do something with the texture
                    //var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial( {    map:          //texture} );
                    //} );

                    // END Clara.io JSON loader code
                    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                }

                //
                function animate() {
                    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                    render();
                }
                function render() {
                    camera.position.x = 400;//vertical camera angle
                    camera.position.y = 300;
                    camera.position.z = 150;

                    camera.lookAt( scene.position );
                    renderer.render( scene, camera );
                }
            </script>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MeshNormalMaterial` is probably not the type of material you want.
Try `MeshBasicMaterial` or `MeshPhongMaterial`.

Description of MeshNormalMaterial taken from [here](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/MeshNormalMaterial)

> A material that maps the normal vectors to RGB colors.

Scroll down the left side of the [three.js docs](https://threejs.org/docs/) to see the other types of materials available.

**EDIT..**
Your never add the material onto the object..

**EDIT..**
Adding some example code. I will use ObjectLoader as you seem to have this working.

```
// Create material for later use.
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
// Create ObjectLoader.
var objectLoader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
// Initiate load of model
objectLoader.load("blue-dog1.json", function(obj) {
  // The documentation for ObjectLoader says it can't load geometries.. confusing (I have never used the ObjectLoader class)
  // But since you say it is working, we'll run with it.
  // obj will be an Object3D, so we must traverse it's children and add the material (I think).
  obj.traverse(function(child) {
    if(child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
      child.material = material;
    }
  }
  // Now the Object is loaded and the material is applied..
  // Add it to the scene (maybe do this after the texture is loaded?).
  scene.add(obj);
  // Load the texture.
  var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
  loader.load("dogtexture.jpg", function(texture) {
    // Apply texture to material.
    material.map = texture;
    // Maybe this is needed.
    material.needsUpdate = true;
  }
}
```

This code is untested, and there might be some closure issues, but it should get you on the right track.
If you cant get this working, try searching for examples using the JSONLoader class.

Comment: hello, thank for your reply. The materials i was experimenting with. However, I tried them both and nothing makes a difference to the model.

Comment: because the model has a default material, the one you create in the texture loader callback is never added to your model

Comment: I just used the example from the documentation of textureloader, how would I go abouts that.

Comment: Maybe consider using the [JSONLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Loaders/JSONLoader) class instead of ObjectLoader

Comment: hi, i've tried other loaders, but this is the only i can seem to get it to work

Comment: i've also edited the code added another version of a object/json texture loader if this is any better, but the problem is still the same with it doesn't load the texture onto the model

Comment: Your new code does not add the material to the object....and tries to add the texture to the scene? `scene.add( obj,texture );`????   I will add some code to my answer

Comment: I was experimenting trying to get it to work for code you mentioned in the comment and thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much, took me bit of fiddling with the code, turns all i had to add were couple of brackets and semi-colons, but nevertheless its still works :)